# silverlight / wpf two way communication with server side app

Tags: wpf, silverlight, wcf, communication, two-way

I have business logic in one application, let's call it "server". I want to "observe" what's going on in this application using a silverlight or WPF app.

So I've figured, I will use WCF services that expose current state to my clients, and I will poll for updates on a regular basis.

It's working well, but I need some kind of two way communication, because I need to notify my clients about changes.

Is there any other way than polling?

Comment: This may help some one http://eneter.blogspot.com/2010/11/silverlight-how-to-receive-messages.html?showComment=1331198714279#c7370731825042576434

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731064.aspx

Comment: Yes, you're right. I did know about polling duplex. But I wasn't convinced if this is a good solution performance wise.

Answer (score 2):

For Silverlight, there is a PollingDuplex mode, which still results in polling, but has a somewhat easier API to work with than dealing with the polling yourself.

See this article on MSDN : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645027(VS.95).aspx

For WPF, I believe there are more efficient ways to do this, but I'm not as familiar with the full WCF stack.